# Need to center text of TextBlock in RadioButton styled as a ToggleButton

Tags: wpf, xaml

Tried using a Label as well.

The text in the button is being left aligned.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonLinks}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"                                 
                             Margin="5"
                             Background="{x:Null}"
                             Height="40"
                             FontSize="14"
                             GroupName="Views"
                             FontWeight="Normal"
                             cal:Message.Attach="ShowPage">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BtnText}"
                               TextAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </RadioButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

ETA:

I'm using MahApps.Metro overlay and when I remove the controls resource in the App.xaml it works, basically is there a way to override a property like alignment on a resource you pull in?

The line I remove from app.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
```

Comment: The button's text is centered for me. what is your "cal:Message.Attach" property?

Comment: sorry, realized the mahapps.metro is doing it, now wondering if there is a way to override just that one property.  When I take out the resource it is centered correctly but I still want the button design/style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to override HorizontalAlignment for a RadioButton which was being set to "Left" in the mahapps library.